# Javascript referencing elements with duplicate attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html such as the following:

```
<form name="test_form">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="560">
<input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="test product">
<input type="hidden" name="product_type" value="7">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="560">
</form>
```

Note that there are two attributes with the a value of "569" for the "name".

Later on, javascript is used too look up the product_name value in the following manner:

```
var c = $("[name='test_form']");
var product_name = c.product_name.value;
```

Believe me, I understand how terrible this code is. However, I have inherited a codebase that was written like this with duplicate attributes and javascript is scattered around referencing the attributes in the above manner. I will ultimately fix this with something more elegant, but in the meanwhile, need something to patch it up. The product_name is successfully looked up in firefox, but it fails in google chrome. Anyone know of a quick fix for this without going through the code and removing the duplicate attributes? Basically, I just need the product_name variable part to read the product_name attribute properly in google chrome despite the presence of multiple elements with that name (luckily, all elements with that attribute name have the same value). Once again, this is something I just need as a temporary patch, so please don't get out the pitchforks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating a jQuery object you cannot use `product_name` for querying the DOM, you can use `find()` and `val()` methods, note that using attribute selector alone is not efficient, it would be better to use tag selector at first.

```
var $c = $("form[name='test_form']");
var product_name = $c.find('input[name="product_name"]').val();
```

If you want to get the value of the input using your current code, you should convert the jQuery object to a DOM Element object, you can use `[index]` or `get(index)` method.

```
var $c = $("form[name='test_form']");
var product_name = $c[0].product_name.value;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d7YEV/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you should use it also for getting elements values.

so instead of

```
var c = $("[name='test_form']");
var product_name = c.product_name.value;
```

you should use

```
var product_value = $('form[name="test_form"] input[name="product_name"]').val()
var product_type = $('form[name="test_form"] input[name="product_type"]').val()
```